# getInitialProps never gets called...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to React and Next.js, so bear with me. But I've spent three hours searching, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

`this.props.test` doesn't output anything, even though it seems like it should output 'test'.

It's like `getInitialProps` is never even called.

```
class Example extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps() {
    return {
      test: 'test'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hi {this.props.test}</h1>
    )
 } 

}
```

Comment: Where are you consuming `Example`? From the docs: `Note: getInitialProps can not be used in children components. Only in pages.`

Comment: `Example` is a page or its a page's child?

Comment: This worked for me just fine. assuming the file is in pages, and it is exported like export default class Example

Answer (score 37):

I came here with the same problem, and my Component *was* in `/pages` so the other answers didn't really help.

My issue was that I was using a custom App (`/pages/_app.js`) and it had a `getInitialProps` in it.

It's a little vague in the documentation, but in the [custom app example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-app) it does mention (emphasis mine):

> Only uncomment [getInitialProps] if you have blocking data requirements for every single page in your application. **This disables the ability to perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to be server-side rendered.**

This essentially means that if your custom `_app.js` has a `getInitialProps` method, you are telling Next.js that this is the only blocking data and every other page component can just be assumed to not have or need their own `getInitialProps`. If you have one anyway, it'll be ignored and that's where my problem was.

This was solved by calling the `getInitialProps` on the page component from inside the `getInitialProps` for the custom App.

```
// pages/_app.js
const App = ({Component, pageProps }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <AppHeader />
    <Component {...pageProps />
  </React.Fragment>
)

App.getInitialProps = async ({Component, ctx}) => {
  let pageProps = {}
  if(Component.getInitialProps){
    pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
  }
  return { pageProps }
}

// pages/home.js
const Home = ({name}) => <div>Hello world, meet {name}!</div>

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return { name: 'Charlie' }
}

export default Home
```

I'm not sure why you can't return `pageProps` directly (nothing gets passed), but it seems to be something special and it's working for me now, so..

Comment: This fixed up my issue, perfect! 

Answer (score 25):

Because `getInitialProps` only works for Pages in Next.js, the correct method for child components is `componentDidMount` with `setState` instead of `props`.

Comment: This is so useful, thank you for sharing this! If only I had read the documentation closer sooner ...

Comment: The answer I've been looking for half an hour. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `pages/_app.js` file if it's your case.

That happens because _app.js overrides the defaults of NextJS.

If you still want to use `getInitialProps` along with ***_app.js*** you must declare this very function inside _app.js:

Inside ***_app.js***:

```
export default class MyApp extends App {
 static async getInitialProps(appContext){

  // your logic goes here

  return {}
 }
 
 render(){
  const {Component} = this.props;

  return (
   <Layout>
    <Component />
   </Layout>
  )
 }
}
```